# How get center of irregular shape in THREE.JS:

Tags: three.js

I'm new to THREE.JS and I'm trying to find the center of a 3D object with an irregular shape. I'm using Box3 to help me, but the center found in it is different from the real center of the 3D object, is there any way to find it?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GmXiO.png)

Box3().setFromObject().getCenter(new THREE.Vector3()) has no problem when working with squares, circles and other simpler shapes

Comment: Finding the center of an arbitrary 3D body is not an easy problem. Can you simplify/limit your problem? Does it have to be exact? Are your objects limited in some way that would make the problem easier? Does it have to be the true gravitational centre, or can the user be tricked?

Comment: It doesn't need to be the exact gravitational center, and it doesn't need to be exactly in the center of the shape, but the closer to the center the better. Imagine that below this geometric shape there is a "carpet", when I find the center of the object, it needs to be exactly above this "carpet" which has the same geometric shape as the 3D object.

Comment: If I use the raycaster and click on the places where this "carpet" is, it works, but if I change the camera's position or touch a place where the intersection point is not the same as where this "carpet" is, I end up having a problem of not knowing exactly where I should direct my destination.

Comment: The idea of ​​the project is that when clicking on a 3D object, I direct a sphere from the current position to the selected 3D object, in such a way that the sphere is inside (center) of the selected 3D object

Comment: Right, so rather than an actual center, you want to choose a point that is always guaranteed to be inside the object, and probably feel somewhat centric to the user. You're just going to have think about it and come up with a definition of your center, and algorithm that that works for you. It's easy to pick a point inside the object (just pick the first or random triangle on your mesh, and a point on that), but it's not going to be centric.

Comment: I imagine I will have to use THREE.Triangle to find the faces, correct? And to find the vertices I must access geometry.attributes.position.array, right? Looking at this array, does each element correspond to an axis? 0 = x, 1 = y, 2 = z, 3 = x, 4 = y, 5 = z...?

Comment: That would depend on how your object is defined. But yes, for a basic mesh with a `BufferGeometry`, you can just go through the position attribute array. They are stored in a flat manner, like `[p0.x, p0.y, p0.z, p1.x, p1.y, p1.z, ...]`. If the geometry has index attributes too, then those define the triangles. If you need help with this, I suggest asking a new question about that specifically.